# mocking testing merge of cells in excel

Tags: c#, excel, moq

I have class working with excel worksheet.
How to you write test to prove that Merge method gets called.

```
/// <summary>
        /// Merges the cells together.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="ws">The worksheet.</param>
        /// <param name="cellsToMerge">The cells to merge.</param>
        /// <exception cref="System.ArgumentNullException">ws;Worksheet has to be defined</exception>
        /// <exception cref="System.ArgumentException">Cells cannot contain null or empty string;cellsToMerge</exception>
        public void MergeCellsTogether(Worksheet ws, string cellsToMerge)
        {
            if(ws==null) throw new ArgumentNullException("ws","Worksheet has to be defined");
            if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(cellsToMerge))throw new ArgumentException("Cells cannot contain null or empty string", "cellsToMerge");

            var cells = ws.Cells[cellsToMerge]; // failing to setup
            ws.Range[cells].Merge();
        }
```

now my test is using MOQ

```
[TestMethod]
        public void TestForMergingCellsTogether()
        {
            // assign
            var cellsToMerge = "A1:C3";

            // mock
            var ws = new Mock<Worksheet>();
            var range = new Mock<Range>();
            ws.Setup(x => x.get_Range(It.IsAny<object>(), It.IsAny<object>())).Returns(range.Object);

// this is part that is giving my headake           
ws.Setup(x => x.Cells[It.IsAny<object>(),It.IsAny<object>()]).Returns(range.Object);


            range.Setup(x => x.Merge(It.IsAny<object>()));
            // act 
            var ps = new RenderProcess("fileName");
            ps.MergeCellsTogether(ws.Object, cellsToMerge);

            // assert
            range.VerifyAll();
        }
```

Comment: Whilst very commendable, you are going to end up with a brittle test if you try to mock something like Worksheet. Have you considered leaning more towards an integration test where you test using the a real spreadsheet inside a memory stream?

Comment: How about warpping the merge in a small private method, you can than verify that it is called, assuming that it does in fact merge the cells.

Comment: @JackHughes the fact of mocking the worksheet is quite good idea as worksheet is an interface. I prefer not to run integration test, for verifying this function, as I will hit different issues with excel :(

Comment: @omerschleifer I have tought about it, but did not decided against it, as the issue will be moved to different method instead of resolving.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found solution to my question.
My approach was incorrect.

My updated(simplified) code

```
/// <summary>
        /// Merges the cells together.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="worksheet">The worksheet.</param>
        /// <param name="cellsToMerge">The cells to merge.</param>
        /// <exception cref="System.ArgumentNullException">ws;Worksheet has to be defined</exception>
        /// <exception cref="System.ArgumentException">Cells cannot contain null or empty string;cellsToMerge</exception>
        public void MergeCellsTogether(Worksheet worksheet, string cellsToMerge)
        {
            if(worksheet==null) throw new ArgumentNullException("worksheet","Worksheet has to be defined");
            if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(cellsToMerge))throw new ArgumentException("Cells cannot contain null or empty string", "cellsToMerge");

            worksheet.Range[cellsToMerge].Merge();
        }
```

And my tests method:

```
 // assign
                var cellsToMerge = "A1:C3";

                // mock
                var ws = new Mock<Worksheet>();
                var range = new Mock<Range>();
                ws.Setup(x => x.get_Range(It.IsAny<object>(), It.IsAny<object>())).Returns(range.Object);

                range.Setup(x => x.Merge(It.IsAny<object>()));
                // act 
                var process = new RenderExcel();
                process.CreateExcelWorkSheet("fileName");
                process.MergeCellsTogether((Worksheet)ws.Object, cellsToMerge);

                // assert
                range.VerifyAll();
```